# How should I call create, update, save, etc methods in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a very simple CRUD application using REST API.

So I create a very simple model, serializer and viewset for all these.

And then I noticed that I don't fully understand some basic principals about right use-cases for calling (for example create method for my model instance)

As I understand, django providers several approaches:

1. I can define my CRUD methods inside model class:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
...
    def create(...):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.save()
```

2. I also can create instances using model serializers (seems there is no big difference, because the same save method from model instance is calling):

```
class FooSerializer(seializer.ModelSerilizer):
...
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
....
    def create():
        fs = self.Meta.model()
        fs.save()
```

2b. I can use simple serializers:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def create(**validated_data):
        return Foo(**validated_data)
```

3. Finally I can use perform_create, update and so on from viewset:

```
class FooView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer = FooSerializer
    def perform_create():
        serializer.save()
...
```

Is there some patterns when one or another solution should be implemented?
Could you please provide some explanation with use cases?
THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go step by step on your points of creating/using `create` method:

1. You don't need to write a `create()` method inside model.
2. You don't need to write a `create()` method in model serializer, unless you want to handle additional keywords or override the `create()` method to change the default behavior([**`Reference`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)).
3. In `serializer.Serializer` you can write a `create()` method if you want save an instance with that serializer. Useful when you are using this serializer with `GenericAPIViews` or `Viewsets`. Reference can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).
4. By writing `perform_create()` method in Viewset, you are basically overriding the default `perform_create()` from the Viewset. You can integrate additional tasks inside that function when overriding it([**`example`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#saveanddeletionhooks)).

Comment: But why just don't use create inside model? Why I need create in serializer or in generic views?

Comment: You don't need to unless you want to override any default behavior. You can simply use a ModelSerializer and Viewset/Generic view.